# Неопределённая ссылка на pthread_create

Tags: linux, c

Я использую библиотеку `pthread.h` на линукс в `eclipse`. Зажав ctrl, можно перейти по ссылке в исходный код функции, то есть файлы есть. Но при попытке создать поток, я получаю:

```
неопределённая ссылка на pthread_create
```

Как бы я не вызывал `pthread_create`.

Помогите настроить Eclipse.

Comment: Флаг `-pthread`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, куда?

Comment: Не пользовался eclipse, поэтому не знаю. :) Во флаги линковщика.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, я его там не нашел. Я ещё думаю над выбором редактора(codeblocks). спасибо

Comment: Советую visual studio code, желательно с плагином clangd вместо стандартного C/C++ от мелкомягких.